# Displaying retrieve data in different table

Tags: php, html

Okay, what I want is to display retrieved data in a table form database, I want my table to be limit in 5 data per table. I need the tables to be display horizontally.

Like this:

```
while($row1 = sqlFetchArray($row)) 
{   $ctr = 0;
$ctr+1;
if($ctr=1 || $ctr<=5)
{
$html .='<table width="100px" style="float:left;"><tr><td>'.$row1['id'].'</td></tr></table>';
}
if($ctr=6 || $ctr<=10)
{
$html .='<table width="110px" style="float:left;"><tr><td>'.$row1['id'].'</td></tr></table>';
}
if($ctr=11 || $ctr<=15)
{
$html .='<table width="120px" style="float:left;"><tr><td>'.$row1['id'].'</td></tr></table>';
}
}

Output:
1    6
2    7
3    8
4    9
5    10
```

Comment: What have you tred so far?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i updated my question with my latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(But the function sqlFetchArray as to work like mysql_fetch_array)

```
<?php

    $limit = 15;

    for($numberCounter = 0; $numberCounter < $numberCount = mysql_num_rows($row); $numberCounter++) {

        $count  = 0;

        if($numberCounter >= mysql_num_rows($row))
            break;

        if ($count == 0 || $count % $limit == 0)
            echo "<table width='100px' style='float:left;'>"; 

        while ($row1 = sqlFetchArray($row) && $count < $limit) {
            if($numberCounter >= mysql_num_rows($row))
                break;

            echo "<tr><td>" . $row1[$numberCounter] . "</td></tr>";
            $count++;   
            $numberCounter++;
        }

        if($count == 0 || $count % $limit == 0)
            echo "</table>";

    }

?>
```

As an example:

```
<?php

    $test = range(1, 43);
    $limit = 15;

    for($numberCounter = 0; $numberCounter < $numberCount = count($test); $numberCounter++) {

        $count  = 0;

        if($numberCounter >= count($test))
            break;

        if ($count == 0 || $count % $limit == 0)
            echo "<table width='100px' style='float:left;'>"; 

        while ($count < $limit) {
            if($numberCounter >= count($test))
                break;

            echo "<tr><td>" . $test[$numberCounter] . "</td></tr>";
            $count++;   
            $numberCounter++;
        }

        if($count == 0 || $count % $limit == 0)
            echo "</table>";

    }

?>
```

Comment: It only giving me data the 5th ,10th and 15th data

Comment: @Ralfh added an example! Also be sure to copy the entire code form the first code block

Comment: @Ralfh didn't you want it horizantally? (maybe edit your question how you want it)

Comment: @Ralfh but you now that after a while 6 will appear on the left side but it's already on the right?